# TigerVNC session timeout

Tags: fedora, vnc

I have installed `TigerVNC` on my DigitalOcean FE24 box following https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-TigerVNC.html.

I start my vnc server with the command

```
$ systemctl start vncserver@:0.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'vncserver@:0.service'.
Authenticating as: user
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Job for vncserver@:0.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status vncserver@:0.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This keeps happening after hardly a minute I run the command and the VNC access is lost.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Editing the file `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` solved it for me, specifically by removing the following lines:

`ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i`

`PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H%i.pid`

I had this exact problem, which also was causing the service to fail on boot (when it was enabled via `systemctl enable vncserver@:0.service`. Starting the service manually (via `systemctl start vncserver@:0.service`) would disconnect connected VNC clients after about a minute or so.

I happened upon [the answer](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?p=1781244&postcount=12) in [this thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=311448) via fedoraforum.org, so credits to them!